# Java console output using two dimensional arrays

Tags: java

I'm looking for insight as to how to print two dimensional arrays from left to right as opposed to cascading down the page with newline characters.

I've written a simple program for an undergraduate A.I. course that solves that little 9-tile games.

```
public void printNode(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
        System.out.printf("[ ");
        for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
            System.out.printf(" " + state[i][k] + " ");
        }
        System.out.printf("]\n");
    }
}
```

This prints the two dimensional array with no problems.

But I'm looking for a way to print the arrays from left to right so I don't have to turn in 50+ pages of transformations to prove my program works. Has anyone solved this problem before?

```
[ 1 2 3 ] [1 2 3]
[ 8 0 4 ] [8 0 4]
[ 7 6 5 ] [7 6 5]
```

This is the effect I want to create. The solution path of transformations is a series of pointers leading back up the chain. Each of my Node's has a pointer to its ancestor. So I can easily follow the pointers back and print them all.

Comment: Since Java does not deal with pointers it's not clear what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to get into implementation details here, but here's some steps you can take

- print all of the top rows of every matrix, so you'll have a string like

> [ 1 2 3 ] [1 2 3]

- add a newline, and print the next row of all the matricies.

> [ 1 2 3 ] [1 2 3]
>   [ 8 0 4 ] [8 0 4]

- continue until entire matrix is printed.

> [ 1 2 3 ] [1 2 3]
>   [ 8 0 4 ] [8 0 4]
>   [ 7 6 5 ] [7 6 5]

essentially you iterate through each matrix equal to their heights.  If they have different heights, you can start skipping the shorter ones, and just leave a blank space in it's place.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void printTwoNodes(int arr[], int arr2[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
        System.out.printf("[ ");
        for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
            System.out.printf("" + arr[i][k] + " ");
        }
        System.out.printf("]");
        System.out.printf("[ ");
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            System.out.printf("" + arr2[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.printf("]\n");
    }
}
```

Can and should be improved